# Taking product lists based on filter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to filter prices based on the start and end price. I have created lists in `Controller` here:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<CarModel> objCar = new List<CarModel>()
    {
        new CarModel {ProductBrand="BMW",ProductName="X4", ProductColor="White", Price=57000 },
        new CarModel {ProductBrand="Mercedes",ProductName="AMG", ProductColor="Black", Price=61000 },
        new CarModel {ProductBrand="BMW",ProductName="X6", ProductColor="Black", Price=32000 },
        new CarModel {ProductBrand="BMW",ProductName="X5", ProductColor="White", Price=28000 },
        new CarModel {ProductBrand="BMW",ProductName="X3", ProductColor="White", Price=30000 }
    };

    CarModelDetail ObjCarDetails = new CarModelDetail();
    ObjCarDetails.OrderDetails = objCar;
    return View(ObjCarDetails);
}
```

In the browser, the table is indicated based on these lists. And there are inputs which one of them is for starting price and the second is for ending price. If the user enters start and end price then clicks the `Filter` button, it should be filtered. Any ideas for this? Help is appreciated!

have look picture [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6xSV.png)

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6xSV.png):

Comment: What is your problem? To find those elements within the price-range? You didn´t provide any code that shows what you´ve tried to achieve this. Juist search abit for "filter list based on condition c#".

Answer (score 0):

use linq

```
var result  = objCar.Where(a => a.Price >= MinValue && a.Price  <= MaxValue).ToList();
```

it will return record that its price more than minimum value and less than max value..  `minimum value` and `maximum value` are the entered value from view

Comment: in view how can I express this?

Answer (score 0):

i do something like this for you;)
[see this](https://codepen.io/monika-biaa/pen/aaKWqq)

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
function( settings, data, dataIndex ) {
    var min = parseInt( $('#min').val(), 10 );
    var max = parseInt( $('#max').val(), 10 );
    var columntosearch = parseFloat( data[2] ) || 0; // use data for the age column

    if ( ( isNaN( min ) && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( isNaN( min ) && columntosearch <= max ) ||
         ( min <= columntosearch   && isNaN( max ) ) ||
         ( min <= columntosearch   && columntosearch <= max ) )
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});


var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// Event listener to the two range filtering inputs to redraw on input
$('#min, #max').keyup( function() {
    table.draw();
} );
```

You have to add this to your view
`https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css`

controller

```
public ActionResult Index(){
return View();}public ActionResult LoadData()
    {
         List<CarModel> objCar = new List<CarModel>()
{
    new CarModel {ProductBrand="BMW",ProductName="X4", ProductColor="White", Price=57000 },
    new CarModel {ProductBrand="Mercedes",ProductName="AMG", ProductColor="Black", Price=61000 },
    new CarModel {ProductBrand="BMW",ProductName="X6", ProductColor="Black", Price=32000 },
    new CarModel {ProductBrand="BMW",ProductName="X5", ProductColor="White", Price=28000 },
    new CarModel {ProductBrand="BMW",ProductName="X3", ProductColor="White", Price=30000 }
};
CarModelDetail ObjCarDetails = new CarModelDetail();
ObjCarDetails.OrderDetails = objCar;
        return Json(new { data = objCar }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

in view:

```
<table class="table table-condensed" id="countryTable">
<thead>
    <tr class="table-success">
        <th>ProductBrand</th>
        <th>ProductName</th>
        <th>ProductColor</th>
        <th>Price</th>

    </tr>
</thead>
```

js:

```
var oaTable = $('#countryTable').DataTable({
 "processing": true, // for show progress bar
 "orderMulti": false, // for disable multiple column at once
 "searching": false,
 // "dom": "<<'pull-left'>'row'>Ftr<'row-fluid'<'col-md-12'lp>>",
 "ajax": {
     "url": "/Yourcontrollername/LoadData",
     "type": "POST",
     "datatype": "json"
 },
 "columns": [{
         "data": "ProductBrand",
         "name": "ProductBrand",
          "width": "150px",
     },
     "columns": [{
         "data": "ProductName",
         "name": "ProductName",
          "width": "150px",
     },
      "columns": [{
         "data": "ProductColor",
         "name": "ProductColor",
          "width": "150px",
     },
      "columns": [{
         "data": "Price",
         "name": "Price",
          "width": "150px",
     },

 ]
```

});

Comment: mrsWhite thanks a lot:) for your help but I know this method. Unfortunately I need to do this in asp.net mvc))

Comment: on server side? it is work in asp.net mvc  :) if you want i can send you

Comment: no just need to write code in C# mvc controller and send to the view. In view it renders when click Filter btn). But I cannot do this in C#

Answer (score -1):

This is just off the top of my head.

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Filter by Car", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.DropDownList("carFilter", new SelectList(@ViewBag.Cars),
        "All Cars", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Then, in your controller:

```
ViewBag.Cars = ListofCars();
private IEnumerable<string> ListofCars()
{
    CarRepo = new CarRepo();

    IEnumerable<CarModel> CCars;
    using (car)
    {
        CCars = cars.SelectAll() as IList<CarModel>;
    }

    var Cars = Cars.Select(b => b.Car).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
    return cities;
}
```

This pulls the view data of the list of cars into the controller, turns them into an `IList` so your controller can sort through them, using lambda expressions. Just a thought.

Comment: OP doesn´t want to select from a dropdown-menu, but just those elemenst in a list whose price is within a given range. Your code doesn´t provide *anything* about that. Apart from this `var Cars = Cars...` won´t even compile

Comment: Yes I do not need dropdown list. But i wrote some code. They also do not provide filter

Comment: Well, I suppose the filter *is* the question being asked.